Toggle switch from button and capacitor
In my head I see it something like this:

What it must to do? When I push button first, capacitor will charge and LED will emit(B->C in transistor). Before capacitor will be discharged and while led is emitting, I wanna to push button again and discharge capacitor through resistor (C->E,  charge from capacitor to resistor and with battery). Sort of turn on / turn off. How to achieve this?

No power supply, collector side?

I think to use collector for discharging. And Base-Emitter for charging.

Also I tried to use mirrored horizontally NPN - same...

No current will run back through emitter to collector.

SPDT pushbutton switch.

For learning purposes - sort of memory.

As it is now, pushing the button will burn up the transistor and/or the LED. It has no memory.

ok i mirrored transistor.

A very easy way to do it is to use two inverters, say 74HC2G14, in a feedback loop. This forms a latch that remains in a stable state.
When SW1 is in the default position, C1 stores the opposite state of that of the output that drives the LED.
Once SW1 changes position, this inverted voltage overrides the feedback through R1, and the latch changes state.
With the DPST switch SW1a, the storage capacitor is connected either to the NOT1 input or output. With the SPST switch SW1, the capacitor remains connected to NOT1 output. To avoid forming a multivibrator that will switch states repeatedly, a differentiator formed by C2 is used to inject an inverted pulse into the input of NOT1. Afterwards, C1 charges slowly via R3, and the slope derived by C2 is too small to change the state of NOT1 again.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The two-inverter circuit can of course also be realized with two NPN (or PNP) transistors. Those can also be in a single tiny SMD package, so there's not much advantage to a transistorized solution if the double inverter is available. The transistors will tolerate much higher supply voltages though.
Below, we simply replaced NOT1 and NOT2 with NPN inverters.

simulate this circuit

Your proposed circuit is sadly never going to work in the way you would like. I show here an LTSpice simulation of a circuit that will allow a simple TACT pushbutton switch to toggle an LED on and then off with successive presses of the button.

In this circuit the TACT switch is simulated with a "voltage controlled switch" so that the simulation can act to pretend to press the button multiple times.
The waveform capture below shows the simulated button press in the top waveform when it is high at 3V which means switch ON. The lower waveform shows the current through the LED which toggles for each button press.

